# Is there anything similar to WPF-DataTrigger in WinUI UWP project?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, winui-3

I want to change the style based on binding values, for this I used DataTriggers in WPF. Now I'm trying to achieve the same in WinUI project, but since there are no DataTriggers in WinUI I can't go further.

In further analysis, I found the package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.WinUI.Managed to use behaviors in WinUI project but I can't install this in WinUI UWP project.

Note: Since VisualStateManager only includes common states I can't apply that here.

Comment: No, As I already mentioned the package cannot be installed in WinUI.UWP project but working fine with WinUI Desktop project. I have also logged an issue report regarding this, for your reference https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors/issues/210

Comment: Do you make WinUi app with WinUI 3 project Template ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using WinUI templates - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Microsoft-WinUI.WinUIProjectTemplates

Comment: Please refer the following answer use `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed`,  but not `WinUI.Managed`.

Comment: could Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed nuget install your project?

Comment: Yes, but UWP managed package behaviors cannot be used with WinUI elements. since namespaces for controls are different. Ex, UWP => Windows.UI.xaml.Controls and WinUI => Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.  UWP.Managed package using Windows namespace so that won't work with WinUI. As of now I'm using converters to achieve my requirements but it would be better if DataTriggers are available.

Comment: The DataTriggers  is made base on property watcher, please refer this case reply and make custom [DataTriggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940904/7254781).

Answer (score 1):

> I found the package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.WinUI.Managed to use behaviors in WinUI project but I can't install this in WinUI UWP project.

The available xaml behaviors package is [`Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/), you could install it into your uwp project, and use `DataTriggerBehavior` to control you xaml base on the specific bindind data.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="DataTriggerRectangle">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" ComparisonCondition="GreaterThan" Value="50">
            <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=DataTriggerRectangle}" PropertyName="Fill" Value="{StaticResource PaleYellowBrush}"/>
        </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" ComparisonCondition="LessThanOrEqual" Value="50">
            <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=DataTriggerRectangle}" PropertyName="Fill" Value="{StaticResource RoyalBlueBrush}"/>
        </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Rectangle>
```

Here is official [document](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki) that you could refer, and here is official [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors/tree/master/samples).